# Could someone explain this build error to me?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

We have a flutter app with a fluter-native plugin that we have written to host any native config code required for the mparticle flutter sdk.
We've implemented the mparticle flutter SDK in the flutter portion (pubspec.yaml) in the plugin.  I can build locally (including a signed release apk).  But when the pipeline tries to build to firebase we get this error:

```
Could not resolve project :mparticle_flutter_sdk.
     Required by:
         project :sofi_native_plugin
      > No matching variant of project :mparticle_flutter_sdk was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'develop', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.2.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
....
Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability com.mparticle.mparticle_flutter_sdk:mparticle_flutter_sdk:1.0-SNAPSHOT declares a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.2.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'develop'
```

I'm expecting it to just build. Tried building it locally with a signed app and it worked perfectly.